# TlsPremasterSecret SecretKeyFactory not available

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I'm getting this error during handshake to an https URL. How can I add a specific SecretKeyFactory? The error has to be related to the https setup of this specific URL because to other similar URLs I don't get that error.
I'm using JDK 1.8.0_162

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not generate secret
        at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(DHCrypt.java:219)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1106)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
        at de.martinm.tools.EBICS.EBICSKernel.fetchHPB(EBICSKernel.java:918)
        at de.martinm.tools.EBICS.EBICSKernel.doFetch(EBICSKernel.java:675)
        at de.martinm.tools.EBICS.EBICSKernel.checkBankKeys(EBICSKernel.java:2013)
        at de.martinm.tools.EBICS.MyIFPEBICS.process(MyIFPEBICS.java:126)
        at de.martinm.tools.EBICS.MyIFPEBICS.main(MyIFPEBICS.java:144)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TlsPremasterSecret SecretKeyFactory not available
        at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(SecretKeyFactory.java:122)
        at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:160)
        at iaik.security.dh.DHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(Unknown Source)
        at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.generateSecret(KeyAgreement.java:648)
        at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(DHCrypt.java:217)
        ... 16 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.martinm.tools.EBICS.EBICSKernel.doFetch(EBICSKernel.java:679)
        at de.martinm.tools.EBICS.EBICSKernel.checkBankKeys(EBICSKernel.java:2013)
        at de.martinm.tools.EBICS.MyIFPEBICS.process(MyIFPEBICS.java:126)
        at de.martinm.tools.EBICS.MyIFPEBICS.main(MyIFPEBICS.java:144)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception was the IAIK provider which I had to add in my code with

```
IAIK.addAsProvider(false);
```

this provider afterwards mixed up the https communication.
After adding

```
Security.removeProvider("IAIK");
```

add the end of the code that used IAIK the exception did not occur anymore